# Is modifying non-mutable member of non-const object in const method Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, const-cast

[dcl.type.cv](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type?fbclid=IwAR1NiP0xcgW6CdkBCSH99IQuU0AGndhuKw8iYnzPWXlVr8gxIgZOA0z3-wM#cv) provides an interesting example:

> For another example,
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   mutable int i;
>   int j;
> };
> struct Y {
>   X x;
>   Y();
> };
>
> const Y y;
> y.x.i++;                                // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
> y.x.j++;                                // ill-formed: const-qualified member modified
> Y* p = const_cast<Y*>(&y);              // cast away const-ness of y
> p->x.i = 99;                            // well-formed: mutable member can be modified
> p->x.j = 99;                            // undefined: modifies a const member
> ```

which indicates that, via `const_cast`, one may modify `mutable` members of a `const` qualified object, while you can't do that with non-`mutable` members.

To my understanding, this is because of the original `const`ness of `y` itself. What would happen if we got rid of the `mutable` keyword, the `const` qualifier fot `y`, but modified the fields in a `const` method?

Example below:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    std::vector<int> vec{};

    void bar() const {
        auto& raw_ref = const_cast<std::vector<int>&>(vec);
        raw_ref.push_back(0);       // ok?

        auto* raw_this = const_cast<foo*>(this);
        raw_this->vec.push_back(0); // ok?
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f{};
    f.bar();
}
```

Does it exhibit Undefined Behaviour? I would think that it does not, since we're modifying an originally non-`const`, but in a `const` context.

Additionally, notice that I provided two ways of modifying the `vec`. One with non-`const` reference and one with non-`const` pointer to `this` (which was originally `const` in this constext due to `foo::bar` being a `const` method). Do they differ in any particular way, given the question's context? I would assume that both are okay here.

Disclaimer: I am aware of `mutable` keyword, but this desing (not only being flawed) is simply an example. One could assume that the author of the code wanted to prohibit every single way of modifying `vec` except for `push_back`s.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - No, even if the object is declared const, the cast itself is not. *The modification* (or attempt thereof, to be precise) is the UB.

Comment: Even if it's not const in the beginning? Because this should be perfectly fine (or there would not be a purpose of the const cast), shouldn't it?

Comment: It is OK to cast away constness and use the resulting lvalue for modification *iff* the object in question isn't `const` to begin with. It doesn't matter if it's done in a `const` member function or elsewhere. It also doesn't matter if the `const_cast` is applied to a pointer or to a reverence, and which one exactly (to the container object or to the member to be modified).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher - Even then. `const int i = 0; const_cast<int&>(i);` is not UB. But add a modification attempt ... `const_cast<int&>(i) = 1;` and it is.

Comment: And a purpose for the cast may very well be working with third party API that while itself is not const correct, still does not modify its argument.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's when it accesses, yes, not when doing the cast, I agree.

Comment: *via const_cast, one may modify mutable members* One can do so without any cast too.

Comment: I keep on saying UB is when casting when it's accessing :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `y.x.i++;` achieves just that.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Deleting the commnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quoted paragraph actually spelled out exactly what is undefined [[dcl.type.cv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.cv#4)

> Except that any class member declared mutable can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior.

A const reference/pointer to a non-const object doesn't make that object a const object, all your accesses are well-formed.

Comment: Far better said than my original comment!